# PHP var_dump($_SESSION);

Tags: php

I am working on a project and the `$_SESSION['username']` was not echoing I used the var_dump and this is what I got back from that result my question is how do I fix it.

```
    array(4) {
 ["SESS_ID"]=> string(1) "2"
 ["SESS_FIRST_NAME"]=> string(7) "Kevin"
 ["SESS_LAST_NAME"]=> string(6) "Outerbridge"
 ["username"]=> string(0) "" }
```

I am sort of new to this var_dump so I am not sure if it is in your forum I will relook at all that is posted.

Comment: The variable exists and its value is the empty string. How do you fix an empty string?

Comment: show the code you are using to set and retrieve the value, a common problem is not calling session_start() before you both set and retrieve anything from the session global

Comment: If this array were a dog at the vet's, I'd say it's already been "fixed"...

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Answer (score 8):

PHP var_dump() function will display always null for $_SESSIONS.
You can use :

```
 Print_r ($_SESSION);
```

Thought it may help,
Have a nice one

Answer (score 7):

"Fix" what?

`$_SESSION['username']` has the value `""`, or the empty string.

If that's not what you wanted, do whatever you need to do to make that not happen.

I'm sorry that this appears like a useless answer, but really it's a useless question.

Comment: all the strings are in my database as a value but when I call it to use it in the file it is producing nothing. My code on the line that is not producing is $username = $_SESSION['username']; I am not sure why it is showing as an empty string.

Comment: @user807419: It's a variable. It contains whatever you put in there. Put something else in and it will contain something else.

Answer (score 2):

> $_SESSION['username'] was not echoing

It seems like it was potentially echoing an empty value because if you look in your array:

```
["username"]=> string(0) ""
```

contains an empty value

Comment: Yes you did, but I guess we just submitted the reply at roughly the same time.

Comment: okay, sorry (I did it 35:35 you 36:36, I think SO ajax alerted you)

Comment: The AJAX alert is not always instant, nor is a user required to view it.

Answer (score 1):

Your SESSION variable exists, but it is empty. You're filling that variable with an empty string.

Comment: How can I fix this as username is in my table with a value

Comment: I have the code in the line that is coming up empty. $username = $_SESSION['username'];

Comment: but where is `$_SESSION['username']` being filled?

Comment: I am trying to add it to another table which also has username in it all the other values are being adding to the db but this is for some reason the only one empty. I have username in the two tables that I need filled one to take from another and post it when called to the other. the id goes without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you started the session?

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs an answer to this question. In my experience working with $_SESSION global, if you navigate from the original page of a form by opening another instance of the browser, you do not automatically get the same $_SESSION hence the variables are empty. Use the 'action' property of your form to navigate to your processing page so that you have an active session filled with the session variables. Also insure that you have session_start() in some form for each page. This can be easily misunderstood when developing.